# How can I put one photo in the top center of two other photos?

Tags: linux, imagemagick

I have three photos, **a.png, b.png and c.png**, I need to combine them into two rows (top and down) so that **a.png** be in the top center of **b.png** and **c.png** i.e. it looks like

```
   a.png
b.png c.png
```

I used this command

```
convert \( a.png \) \( b.png c.png  +append \) -append combine.png
```

but this command doesn't center **a.png** in the middle of first raw instead the combined photo looks like

```
a.png
b.png c.png
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just add a centering option:

```
convert \( a.png -gravity center \) \( b.png c.png  +append \) -append combine.png
```